# Why are the dimensions of my modal view different from what I expect?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, modal-dialog, viewcontroller, popover

I created this dialog in IB:
[image: dialog]

I set a segue the following way:
[image: segue]

This is how I configured the ViewController:
[image: ViewController]

And this is how I configured the view metrics:
[image: View Metrics]

Here's what I get in the iOS Simulator:
[image]

So: could somebody tell me why, how could I get this they way I visually intend to and where I could find a very good Interface builder tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you allocate/display this modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Form Sheet" modal presentation style always uses the same size container, and you can't override it. With iOS 7 or later, you can define a custom modal presentation style to accomplish what you want, or search GitHub.

Here's an iOS 6-compatible implementation with a custom size.

```
/** Created in answer to mirx's question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803961/why-are-the-dimensions-of-my-modal-view-different-from-what-i-expect/18805374?noredirect=1#comment27741546_18805374 */

@interface AHPresentingViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *presentedBackgroundView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *formController;
@end

@implementation AHPresentingViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UITableViewController *table = [UITableViewController new];
    table.title = @"Form";
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:table];
    table.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissPresentedForm:)];
    [self presentForm:nav size:CGSizeMake(320, 240)];
}
-(void)presentForm:(UIViewController *)formVC size:(CGSize)size {
    if(self.formController) return;
    NSLog(@"Form view: %@",formVC.view);
    UIView *background;
    self.presentedBackgroundView = background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    background.opaque = NO;
    background.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    background.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:background];
    formVC.view.frame = (CGRect){CGPointZero, size};
    formVC.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) / 2., CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) + CGRectGetHeight(formVC.view.bounds));
    [self addChildViewController:formVC];
    self.formController = formVC;
    [self.view addSubview:formVC.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        background.alpha = 0.4;
        formVC.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2., self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.);
    }];
}
-(void)dismissPresentedForm:(id)sender {
    if(!self.formController) return;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.presentedBackgroundView.alpha = 0;
        self.formController.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) / 2., CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) + CGRectGetHeight(self.formController.view.bounds));
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.presentedBackgroundView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.formController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.formController removeFromParentViewController];
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, what could I do now (with iOS6) to get the input dialog the way I want it?

Comment: Edited answer to include example solution